# Como trocar a versão do cordova no ionic?

Tags: ionic, apache-cordova, ionic3, npm

Preciso trocar a versão do cordova de um projeto ionic que estou testando, isso é possível? Se sim, como posso fazer isso? Atualmente tenho essa versão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém gostaria de trocar para a versão 7.0 . Qual comando do npm utilizo?

Answer (score 1):

npm install -g cordova@latest

ou

npm install -g cordova@x.x.x -> onde: x.x.x = versão

Comment: E no caso de atualizar somente localmente?

Comment: O que vc quer dizer com "somente localmente"?

Comment: a versão do cordova dentro de um projeto, não de forma global.

Answer (score 0):

Para usar uma versão anterior você pode fazer assim. Caso você esteja na última versão do ionic:

ionic start myApp2 --v2

ionic start myApp3 --v3

Assim após a instalação você tem a opção de adicionar o cordova correspondente a sua versão instalada, mesmo que você esteja na última versão do cordova